# Trying to get URL parameters to JSF backing bean

Tags: jsp, jsf, url, xhtml, parameter-passing

I'm entering the following url with the following added

?UserID=XBBBB

I'm trying to get the UserID of XBBBB all the way through index.jsp to proauth.xhtml and into my backing bean of ProfileAuthorizationBean.java.

The code is getting all the way through, but the UserID=XBBBB parameter is lost after index.jsp. IOW, the System.out in index.jsp is printing XBBBB to the console and I believe is getting forwarded to proauth.xhtml.  When I pick up with an HttpServletRequest in ProfileuthorizationBean, the parameter for UserID is not there.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
<%
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String UserID = request.getParameter("UserID");
if (UserID != null) {
   System.out.println(UserID);
   response.sendRedirect("proauth.xhtml?UserID=" + UserID);
}
%>
</html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
 <h:head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/local/tinstyle.css"/>
 </h:head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function doSubmit() {
  document.getElementById('proAuthForm:proAuthBtn').click();
 }
 </script>
 <h:body onload="doSubmit()">
 <h:form id="proAuthForm">
<p:commandButton id="proAuthBtn" value="" action="#{profileAuthorizationBean.doProfileAuth}" ajax="false" />  
 </h:form>
 </h:body>
</html>


public String doProfileAuth() {
 String retValue = "landingPage";
 try {

   HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
   System.out.println(request.getParameter("UserID"));
.
.
.
} catch (Exception e) {
}
}
```

Comment: What an extremely strange approach. First of all, why do you have an `index.jsp` in first place? Second of all, why are you submitting a JSF form on page load? After all, what's the concrete functional requirement for which you thought that *this* is the solution?

Comment: @BalusC, appears to be some kind of implementation of the Front Controller pattern for authentication. OP should probably just use a managed bean to process auth. Just my view anyway

Comment: I have the impression that OP never heard of servlet filters or `<f:viewParam>`. In any way, as long as he don't elaborate the concrete functional requirement, it's hard to propose the right solution.